# Allow countries for websites is not working

Tags: configuration, scope, countries, magento2.1.5, website-restriction

I'm trying to configure 2 websites allowing only some countries for each website. For test I'll only allow "spain" for one website and "USA" for the other.

I'm using the VM of bitnami with Magento 2.1.5.

This is the config:

**default scope:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul2yj.png
[image]

**website spain**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8J21.png
[image]

**storeView Spain**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYtp.png
[image]

**website USA**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRHCJ.png
[image]

**storeView USA**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QHvf.png
[image]

This are the checkouts:

Spanish website's checkout url: 172.16.1.246/**es**/checkout/

USA website's checkout url: 172.16.1.246/**in_en**/checkout/

**Checkouts**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFshX.png
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDQyB.png
[image]

Displays the same...

I did all known commands: setup:upgrade, cache:clean, cache:flush, compile, set production, indexer:reindex, etc...

Am I doing something wrong? it has to work this functionality.

Why it displays the same config that spanish website? WHY?

In the DDBB I think it's correct:

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like "%countr%";
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope    | scope_id | path                    | value |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------+
|       118 | websites |        1 | general/country/default | ES    |
|       119 | websites |        1 | general/country/allow   | ES    |
|       120 | websites |        2 | general/country/default | US    |
|       121 | websites |        2 | general/country/allow   | US    |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you

EDIT: I set as default the USA website, and now both websites display only USA on the dropdown...

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any update on this?

Comment: Did you get any solution? please post here